# Covering system of congruences with specific properties?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

A family of residue classes $a_i (\bmod n_i)$ with $2\leq n_1\leq\cdots\leq n_r$, ($r\geq2$) is called a *covering system of congruences* if every integer belongs to at least one of the residue classes, that is, every integer satisfies at least one of the congruences $a_i (\bmod n_i)$. The known examples are:

$0 (\bmod 2),\quad 0 (\bmod 3),\quad 1 (\bmod 4),\quad 5 (\bmod 6),\quad 7 (\bmod 12).$

$0 (\bmod 2),\quad 0 (\bmod 3),\quad 1 (\bmod 4),\quad 3 (\bmod 8),\quad 7 (\bmod 12),\quad 23 (\bmod 24).$

My question is whether  it is possible to construct a (finite with at least two different moduli, or infinite) system of congruences that covers all odd non-square integers using moduli and residue classes satisfying

$$
\left(\frac{a_i}{n_i}\right)=-1,\qquad \text{for}\ \ 1\leq i\leq r
$$

where the parenthesis is the  Legendre (or Jacobi ) symbol.

P.S. What if we make the condition in the question weaker as follows: whether  it is possible to construct a (finite with at least two different moduli, or infinite) system of congruences that covers all odd non-square integers using moduli and residue classes satisfying

$$
\left(\frac{a_i}{n_i}\right)=-1,\ \ \text{or}\ \ 0,\qquad \text{for}\ \ 1\leq i\leq r
$$

Comment: Some congruence has to cover the number 1, so it has to be $1\bmod n_i$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what if we assume odd numbers greater than 1?

Comment: Then some congruence has to cover 9.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what if we consider to cover non perfect square odd positive integers?

Comment: You've said that $n_i\le n_{i+1}$, which would allow using a modulus more than once. I'm going to change it to $n_i\le n_{i+1}$, and also fix your formatting.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, thanks, but I supposed that of course $r\geq2$ and  also possible to have repeated moduli.

Comment: There is no finite covering system. On the contrary, suppose that $(a_i,n_i)$ with $i\in[1,r]$ is a finite covering system of the odd non-square integers. Then no $n_i$ can be a power of $2$. Hence every $n_i$ has an odd divisor $d_i>1$. Fix an odd common multiple $l$ of $\{\,d_i\mid i\in [1,r]\}$ that is not a perfect square. Then some congruence must cover $l$ but $(l/n_i)=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @asad If you want to allow the $n_i$ to be equal, then the examples that you gave are misleading ,since they use different moduli. If you allow the moduli coincide, then by your definition a covering system includes the trivial system $$0\bmod n,\;1\bmod n,\;2\bmod n,\cdots,\;n-1\bmod n.$$

Comment: @JoeSilverman, You are right, as those example that I put are known, but what I am looking for is the condition about quadratic non-residue relation that I imposed above. I added the condition more than one modulus in the question.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, asad?

Answer (score 3):

Given any finite set $n_1,\dots,n_r$ of moduli, there is an odd, nonsquare number $a$ such that the Legendre/Jacobi symbol $(a|n_i)=1$ for all $i$. You can't cover that $a$.

Give it up, asad – quit while you're behind.